# What's the best way to identify which nonparametric groups have the greatest impact on sales?

Tags: nonparametric, survey, excel

I am conducting a survey to improve our understanding of how to improve how we target certain groups of customers and want to identify which factor(s) most likely account for the sales (Total Sales Value, Frequency of Purchase, Units per Transaction, Average Price paid, etc.).  I am expecting a sample of around 2,000 responses.  Characteristics we are collecting include Age Range, Gender, Income Range, Education Level, Marital Status, Type of Job, and aspects such as Satisfaction (Likert Scale) with our products. I therefore have multiple groups of binary, ordinal, and categorical data to compare with the sales.

Samples within each group are likely to be normally distributed, but the sample size is likely to be different (e.g. 18 to 23 vs. 24 to 30, or with differing sample sizes by income bracket).  I am currently considering Kruskal-Wallis approach but am not sure whether this would help me find the answer Im looking for.  I initially want to identify which characteristic most strongly correlates to the sales and then subsequently conduct further analysis to identify which specific group of customers within that category account for the sales.

I don't have access to SPSS so I am limited to what can be achieved through Excel or StatPlus.

I would sincerely appreciate some constructive advice.   Thank you.

Comment: 1. Why would different group sizes matter?  2. I am puzzled by "I don't have access to SPSS so I am limited to what can be achieved through Excel or StatPlus"... there are many more statistics packages than these.

Comment: Thank you for the response. To answer your questions, 1 I believe unequal sample size is problematic for analyses such as ANOVA, F-Test, Chi-Square, etc. 2. Those are what I have currently, do you have a suggestion for a suitable add-in or package that offers a suitable test?

Comment: 1. All the things you mention are designed to work with unequal sample sizes, 2. R is quite comprehensive and is free.  If learning R is somehow daunting, you might consider jamovi, which is built on R and is also free.

Comment: Glen, many thanks for that very useful tip regarding Jamovi. I have now downloaded it and it seems to perfectly suit what I am looking for.